# Date deserialize issue spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My friend has implemented the Spring hibernate mvc in our project and I have been maintaining this for a long time, Recently I've seen malfunctioning date-time when I de-serialize date from MySQL database,

The date format which is saved in database like this `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss(25-03-1658 15:05:45)`.
When retrieve this through spring it actually read like the same above except wrong time format - `25-03-1658 9:03`.

I beleive it has something to do with spring annotation of `JsonFormat` or `JsonFormatDeserializer`. But no luck after one day.

Please help

Comment: Could you please add code snippets/.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your field

```
@JsonDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private Date yourDate;
```

OR

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")
private Date yourDate;
```

Comment: I couldn't find this annotation @JsonDateFormat. Nope it didn't work, let me post the code.